# Where can I find Poverty shapefile?

Tags: census

Does anyone know where I can download shapefile file that has poverty dataset for California?

Comment: You might want to add some more details to this question (e.g. what definition of poverty you are using, what you've already looked at, what data you need - changes over time, and what resolution), since it has been flagged as low-quality for length and content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The U.S. Census Bureau's [TIGER Products](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) have free shapefiles for the American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates and other datasets. These include several measures of income and poverty, including "Poverty Status In The Past 12 Months By Household Type By Age Of Householder", "Poverty Status Of Individuals In The Past 12 Months By Living Arrangement", and "Ratio Of Income To Poverty Level In The Past 12 Months". The datasets can be downloaded by state.